# InnoDB Buffer Pool Size % of Total RAM - (Buffer Pool Size of Total RAM) returning No Data

Tags: mysql, prometheus, grafana, prometheus-node-exporter

I have installed the prometheus [node_exporter](https://github.com/prometheus/node_exporter) running on port `9100` and [mysqld_exporter](https://github.com/prometheus/mysqld_exporter)running in port `9104` and configured [grafana](https://grafana.com/oss/) to use [prometheus](https://prometheus.io/) as the default source.

From the grafana explorer, I can query the `node_memory_MemTotal_bytes` using something like:

```
node_memory_MemTotal_bytes{instance="10.0.0.4:9100"}
```

> notice port 9100 (node_exporter)

And I can query also the `innodb_buffer_pool_size` using:

```
 mysql_global_variables_innodb_buffer_pool_size{instance="10.0.0.4:9104"}
```

> notice port 9104 (mysqld_exporter)

I would like to calculate the `Buffer pool size of total RAM` using:

```
(mysql_global_variables_innodb_buffer_pool_size{instance=~"$host"} * 100) / on (instance) node_memory_MemTotal_bytes{instance=~"$host"}
```

The problem I have is that `$host` is the IP and the port: `10.0.0.4:9104` and can only obtain the  `mysql_global_variables_innodb_buffer_pool_size` from the `mysqld_exporter` and not the `node_memory_MemTotal_bytes` since is in port `9100` because of this I am getting `No Data`

[image: Buffer Pool Size of Total RAM]

Any ideas about how could I mix data the metrics from the `node_exporter` & the `mysqld_exporter`?

This is the prometheus configuration:

```
- job_name: test_mysql
  scheme: http
  static_configs:
  - targets:
    - 10.0.0.4:9104

- job_name: test_node
  scheme: http
  static_configs:
  - targets:
    - 10.0.0.4:9100
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Follow the steps to update buffer pool size-

1. Edit **innodb_buffer_pool_size** [image]
2. MySQL Overview / Edit Panel, replace Metrics `(mysql_global_variables_innodb_buffer_pool_size{instance="$host"} * 100) / on (instance) node_memory_MemTotal_bytes{instance="$host"}`
   into `avg by (node_name) ((mysql_global_variables_innodb_buffer_pool_size{service_name=~""} * 100)) /on (node_name) (avg by (node_name) (node_memory_MemTotal_bytes{node_name=~""}))`

Replace old metric as given below-
[image]

3. Save setting

[image]

Comment: comment picture

Comment: Hi @shelwinsu, could you please elaborate more on how this works `node_name=~""` takes the `$host:port` automatically?

Answer (score 3):

I just spent a whole afternoon to find a fix for it so I thought I would share it in case this can help somebody else.

I was finally able to make it work using the `label_replace` function.

I replaced the original query by the following one:

```
(label_replace(mysql_global_variables_innodb_buffer_pool_size{instance="$host"}, "nodename", "$1", "instance", "(.*):.*") * 100) / on(nodename) (label_replace(node_memory_MemTotal_bytes, "nodename", "$1", "instance", "(.*):.*"))
```

[label_replace](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/functions/#label_replace) allows (among other things) to add a new label, which can be based on the value of an already existing one. In this case, we use it to add a new **nodename** label, which get the value of the instance label (`hostname:port`) from which we remove the `:port` part.

This thus allows to have metrics from different exporters instances sharing a label with the same value and thus use these together when needed (here, we wanted to use the `mysql_global_variables_innodb_buffer_pool_size` metric from the `mysqld_exporter` and the `node_memory_MemTotal_bytes` from the `node_exporter` in the same query, for a given host).

HTH.

Baptiste